# How can I calculate the SHA -1 hash of a string with a secret key in Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, sha1, secret-key

Currently I am working on SHA-1 Hash Algoritham 
can any one suggest me how can such algo be developed using the secret key?

Thanks :-)

Similar question : 
[How can I calculate the SHA-256 hash of a string with a secret key in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050700/how-can-i-calculate-the-sha-256-hash-of-a-string-with-a-secret-key-in-android).

Thanks.

Comment: A hash (or message digest) does not have a secret key. Are you looking for a MAC (message authentication code) algorithm?

Comment: mmmm Algorit-ham *drool*

Comment: Using SHA-1 Algoritham where i should pass the string and secret key so i can encrypt the string and also can decrypt.

Comment: If you are looking for a cipher algorithm (encrypt and decrypt with a secret key) than SHA-1 is not for you. A hash on puropose is one-way. It is practically impossible to recover the original text from the hash.

Comment: Henry thanks :-) Are there any way to encrypt string using SHA-1 ?

Comment: It's like you are asking how to fix a screw with a hammer. It simply isn't the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking of a salt or something ? I think you'd like to use an encryption you can resverse such as AES.

```
  public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception   
  {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  }

  public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception
  {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()]));
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText),"UTF-8");
  }
```

A simple way to use it would be

```
String plaintext = "My plain text.";
String encryptionKey = "Super secret encryption key";
Log.d("AES", "Plain text is : " + plaintext );

byte[] cipher = encrypt(plaintext, encryptionKey);
Log.d("AES", "Encrypted string is : " + new String(cipher));

String decrypted = decrypt(cipher, encryptionKey);
Log.d("AES", "Decrypted string is : " + decrypted);

if (plaintext.equals(decrypted)) Log.d("AES", "Strings match !");
```

Comment: Well, a salt is a random string you concatenate to the string you want to hash, in order to make it harder to reverse. Eg. sha1("Plain text to encryt" + "jdsdiuihfsduqihfsdiuif15454"). "jdsdiuihfsduqihfsdiuif15454" is your salt.

Comment: thanks :-) and let me know where is SHA-1 ? I have to encrypt string using sha-1.

Comment: 2min search: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9071224/1295422

Comment: Code has been updated.

Comment: Thanks :-) helpful and works :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48263/discussion-between-androidgeeks-and-manitoba)

Comment: Here, Getting the No Such Provider Exception coming.